# Update array of objects in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

```
{
"_id" : "x2Yp4hnK8mvHhdYn4",
"fileid" : "kcSMLyR4wZc2gMADq",
"filepath" : "E:/sample/file4.txt",
"filecontent" : [ 
    {
        "path" : "file4.txt",
        "flag" : 0,
        "randno" : "UbEsfTKin9"
    }, 
    {
        "path" : "copy.txt",
        "flag" : 0,
        "randno" : "fcMQU7wk3c"
    }, 
    {
        "path" : "about.txt",
        "flag" : 0,
        "randno" : "kBdKtHu8qQ"
    }
]
```

}

I want to update flag value to 1 for all the filecontent.flag using _id and filecontent.flag : 0 . I used filecontent.$.flag operator which update first matching. But I want to update all the flag objects.

Comment: filecontent.find({ "_id":contentid })
            .forEach(function (doc) {
                
              doc.filecontent.forEach(function (event) {
                if (event.flag === 1) {
                    event.flag = 0 ;
                    console.log(event);
                 }
             });
                   filecontent.save(doc);
     });

Comment: the above code does not work